# Open sums in SQL / dynamic selection of tables

Tags: sql, types

Much ink has been spilled on the topic of sum types in SQL. The standard solutions are called absorption, separation, and partition; see, e.g.: [https://www.inf.unibz.it/~montali/teaching/1415/dpm/slides/4.relational-mapping.pdf](https://www.inf.unibz.it/%7Emontali/teaching/1415/dpm/slides/4.relational-mapping.pdf) .

I want to ask about how to encode open sums. Normal sums allow a field to be one of a fixed set of several different types; with open sums, this set is not fixed.

The basic setup in our program: There is a list of "triggers," where each trigger can be one of many different things. Plugins can be written defining new trigger types, although the set of trigger types can be assumed to be known at compile time.

We want a table of all triggers.

Our current best idea:

1. Dynamically create a materialized view of the following form:

```
    id | id_in_plugin_table | thing_in_main_program_it_refs | plugin_name
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
     1 | 27                 | 8                             | RegexTrigger
     2 | 27                 | 12                            | RidiculouslyUnsafeCustomJSTrigger
```

This relation is automatically generated from the various plugin tables, each of which have their own ID and a `thing_in_main_program_it_refs` field.

For illustration, here's what the referenced tables may look like.

RegexTrigger table:

```
    id | thing_in_main_program_it_refs | regex
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    27 | 8                             | hel*o
```

RidiculouslyUnsafeCustomJSTrigger

```
    id | thing_in_main_program_it_refs | custom_js
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    27 | 12                            | (x) => isPrime(x.length())
```

2. Either use two roundtrips to lookup the plugin table and then query it, or combine them into a single SQL program which uses EXEC.

I'm happy with part 1, but not with part 2. Neither option sounds efficient, and the latter option uses EXEC.

So, we're looking for either (a) a better way to dynamically select a table in a query, or (b) a different approach to open sums.

Comment: Please provide some sample data that illustrates the issue(s) you are facing. If the MV provides you with the information you want then what's the issue with it? If you don't like the MV approach then what's stopping you creating a table instead and populating it at the same time that you populate the tables the MV would be based on?

Comment: I have edited the question to provide some example plugin tables. The MV does not provide the needed information because the needed information is in the plugin-specific tables. It cannot provide this information because that information is heterogeneous and not known at the time the core code is written (but is known when the plugins are written, which are in separate codebases). The key phrase to this question is "open sum."